# GetUserByProviderAccountIdError with Google & Firebase Adapter Next Auth

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth

I was trying to use Google Provider with Firebase Adapter in Next Auth, Once I select an account I get the following error:

I am using Firebase 9

```
TypeError: client.collection is not a function
        at getUserByProviderAccountId (C:\Users\veer4\Documents\Hridaya\Learning\Programming\React JS\google-docs\node_modules\@next-auth\firebase-adapter\dist\index.js:49:26)       
        at acc.<computed> (C:\Users\veer4\Documents\Hridaya\Learning\Programming\React JS\google-docs\node_modules\next-auth\dist\adapters\error-handler.js:19:22)
        at Object.callback (C:\Users\veer4\Documents\Hridaya\Learning\Programming\React JS\google-docs\node_modules\next-auth\dist\server\routes\callback.js:72:51)
        at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
      name: 'GetUserByProviderAccountIdError'
    }
```

My pages/api/[...nextauth].js

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'
import { db } from "../../../firebase-config"
import { FirebaseAdapter } from "@next-auth/firebase-adapter"

export default NextAuth({
    // Configure one or more authentication providers
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        }),
    ],
    adapter: FirebaseAdapter(db),
})
```

Comment: Maybe unrelated to the issue, but shouldn't the `next-auth` configuration be under `/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js` instead?

Comment: Yes it is in auth folder, I wrote it mistakenly in the question

Answer (score 0):

```js
const firestore = (
  firebase.apps[0] ?? firebase.initializeApp(/* here you should pass your config object */)
).firestore()
```

Your `db` should look exactly like `firestore` const, I am not sure if it looks the same, maybe you should update your question if it doesn't look like this.

https://next-auth.js.org/adapters/firebase

Comment: For Firebase 9 ?

Comment: I have it similar to this but a little different

Comment: Please add that into your question too, maybe there is a problem there.

Comment: `const app = !getApps().length ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : FirebaseApp`  `const db = getFirestore();`

Comment: Is this correct?

Comment: `const firestore = (!getApps().length ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : FirebaseApp).firestore()` don't you think that you should do something like this? even though I don't know where are you getting `getApps` or `initializeApp` from. Or what is `getFirestore()` or where you are getting it from.

Comment: `import { initializeApp, getApps, FirebaseApp } from 'firebase/app'`
`import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";`

Comment: According to Firebase Docs I think this is correct

Comment: I think you need to do `const db = getFirestore(app)` according to https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#variables

Comment: getFirestore(app) - `Returns the existing Firestore instance that is associated with the provided FirebaseApp. If no instance exists, initializes a new instance with default settings.` This is the thing that you are missing.

Comment: Thank You! I will try it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237893/discussion-between-hridaya-agrawal-and-nicolae-maties).

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? @HridayaAgrawal

Comment: Not Yet :-( @Lala

Answer (score 0):

For anyone experiencing the same issue, First off to check your firestore rules if user has read and write access.
[read more](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/firegal-be39a/firestore/rules)

Comment: I tried that but no luck, it's still showing the same error